# Any class that provides sorted view of List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, list, generic-list

Is there a class in .NET that works as a read-only ordered view for `List<T>`? Something that has the same relation to `List<T>` that `DataView` has to `DataTable`, so that I could configure the property on which I want this view to be sorted and then the view would monitor the list and automatically update itself when items are added to/removed from the list.

N.B. I could do it using LINQ's `OrderBy` every time I need to iterate over the list, but looking at the number of times I need to iterate, this looks like some overkill.

**Edit:** A `DataView` (as far as I understand) doesn't do recreate an ordered copy of the table rows every time. It takes the sort column name in the constructor and then *keeps an eye* on the underlying `DataTable` for changes and updates itself on-the-fly instead of recreating the view from scratch when we iterate it.

Comment: try dictionary once..but i am completely not sure...

Comment: Dictionaries are key-based. I need a List.

Answer (score 1):

For separate `ViewModel` (so you can have different "shapes" of the same collection presented to the caller) of the collection, there is nothing present in BCL, nor that I'm aware of. So you have to build it yourself. But for tracking changes inside collection (attention, *not objects* inside that collection)  you can use [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)

Comment: I'm more in search of a **CollectionObserver** than `ObservableCollection`, if you see what I mean.

Comment: if you use ObservableCollection the change notifiations will be *pushed* on you, if you usw CollectionObserver you have to "ping" for changes every time. The first case, I think, is better.

Comment: Correct, but what do I do with the change notification; create a new ordered copy of the original list on-the-fly (for every notification)? If you mean this, then that can already be achieved through LINQ's `OrderBy` at runtime, but that is what I'm trying to avoid. If on the other hand, you mean I should use my comparison criterion to place the incoming item at the correct position, then that is precise behavior what I'm looking for **in a built-in class**. :)

Comment: BTW, I don't know if a built-in class already exists with the name **CollectionObserver**. I'm not referring to that. I just wanted to convey my idea with that name.

Comment: @dotNET: yes I understand. But as I said I don't know any built-in type that does what you want actually.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use a [`SortedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx).

It has a [`SortedList(IComparer)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132323.aspx) constructor to which you can pass a custom comparer that defines which fields to sort on.

Comment: OR Generic version of it [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx)

Comment: That is also key-based.

Comment: @Damith Oops, that's what I meant to link to. Updated the links now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use visual control for sorting or filtering your data:

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxSort_snip.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ListBoxSort_snip" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel>
      <ListBox Name="myListBox" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <ListBoxItem>my</ListBoxItem>
        <!--Or you can set the content this way:-->
        <!--<ListBoxItem Content="my"/>-->
        <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Sort</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
      </ListBox>
      <Button Click="OnClick" Width="30" Height="20" DockPanel.Dock="Top">Sort</Button>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>

private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myListBox.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(
        new SortDescription("Content", ListSortDirection.Descending));
}
```

Check out more information in the article - [How to: Sort Data in a View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754073.aspx).

Comment: Ah, no no. This is not WPF. I'm working in plain-old C# (not even WinForms). Try thinking `System.Collections.Generic` to see what I mean.